# Conect my tablet to a TV with HDMI

Tags: video, hdmi, tablet, tv

I have a tablet with ubuntu 11.10 and I want to connect it to my TV. My tablet has a miniHDMI port, I have connected to my TV with a miniHDMI-HDMI cable, and what now? I feel a little silly but I don't know what to do. Can somebody help me? Thanks.

---

Hola. Tengo una tableta con ubuntu 11.10 y quiero conectarla a mi TV. Mi tableta tiene un puerto miniHDMI, la he conectado a mi TV con un cable miniHDMI-HDMI. Me siento un poco tonto, pero no sé qué tengo que hacer ahora. ¿Alguien puede orientarme? Gracias.

Comment: Go to Monitors..

Comment: @uri Sorry, but my TV is not shown in monitors, even if I click on 'Detect monitors'. I've tested powering on first the tablet with the TV poweroff, and first the TV with the tablet poweroff, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question. I needed to install the wetab's chrontel tiitoo driver from http://update.tiitoo.com/source/packages/ There is no .deb package, some manipulation of the .rpm package was needed.

I don't know if this driver will be helpful for another tablets, mine is an ekoore perl (a wetab/exopc clone)

---

Me respondo yo mismo. Tuve que instalar el driver de chrontel de http://update.tiitoo.com/source/packages/ No hay paquete .deb, tuve que manipular el .rpm

Mi tableta es una ekoore perl (el mismo hardware que la wetab o la exopc). No sé si este controlador servirá para otras tabletas